# store data which will not vanish after clear data in android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sqlite

I want to store application installed date in some file or datatabase or sharepreferenece. After particular days suppose 60 days user has not access this free version. And prompt user to buy paid version. But when user clear cache it will  delete this application installed date. Is there is any place where I can store this date,so after clear data also it will be present. I dont want to store it in external sd card.

Or there is any other suggestion so user can not access free version after 60 days. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Create one API, which stores the installed date on your server, with device id mapped.

All other storage will vanish after clear data and if user uninstall the app.

So server is the best place to achieve what you need.